# I can't color some parts of my model

Tags: modeling

I am sorry if someone already asked for this question, I wasn't able to find it anywhere..I googled lots of things and didn't satisfied my needs so I hope you can help me out :) :P.
When I try to hand texture my model, some parts are being unable to be textured.
I hope you understand what I mean, here is a screenshot so I can explain you.
[image: 1]

The blue line is showing where I can't texture it as you can see it's white.
I had to "Fill" to get the white color even though some places got still black as on the picture you can see black texture on the fore-end/near barrel.

Comment: It looks like those are boundary areas in your UV unwrap, and it looks like you are trying to paint or texture areas that are outside the image or too stretched out and causing severe distortions. Have you tried fixing your UV map? Could you post a screenshot of your unwrapped mesh?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's hard to paint some areas in the 3D Window. You may try going to *UV Editor*, change the mode from *View* to ***Paint*** and paint these areas there.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to increase the bleed setting.

When the colour in your image stops right on the edge of your uv's, you can get errors due to floating point accuracy that means you may sometimes get the colour from either side of the line. This happens more when the edges are at an angle on the image texture. By allowing your painting to bleed over the edge a few pixels you ensure that drawing from the image will always get the colour you want. You also need to be sure that you have enough of a gap between uv islands or that neighbouring islands will always use the same colour.

While a little misleading, you can find the bleed setting in the options tab under Project Paint while you are texture painting.

[image: bleed option]